# Combining ENTRYPOINT and CMD in Dockerfile targeting different executables

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have a Dockerfile that defines a `dotnet` ENTRYPOINT. In addition, I have a program that is configured to run under `supervisor` (with a `supervisord.conf` definition). When the container is run, I need to start the supervisor service and also pass several args to the ENTRYPOINT executable. I cannot combine ENTRYPOINT and CMD because CMD args are unrelated to ENTRYPOINT. I'd also like to keep the ENTRYPOINT to explicitly have the container wrap `dotnet` exec. Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

I know my scenario works in entirety since I can attach to a running container then starting the `supervisor` service.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
…
FROM base AS final    
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BLAH.dll"]
CMD ["service", "supervisor", "start"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to run two different services at the same time.
You can't achieve that through the Dockerfile.

I suggest you make a script to run both services.
And use that script in your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Makes sense.  As well I found [this thread on Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/entrypoint-running-a-script-arg-1-is-not-received/24403/3) that has relevant info.